# Wix : How to get the resolution screen from Client properties?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have these properties :

```
Property(S) ScreenX = 1024
Property(S) ScreenY = 768
Property(C) ScreenX = 1920
Property(C) ScreenY = 1080
```

If I use the ScreenX property for example, I obtain only the ScreenX value for property(S).

I would like to get the ScreenX value for property(C) -> client.

Is it possible?

Comment: Couple of tips when posting here: please don't sign your posts (your profile card does that for you) and please don't mark them as urgent/asap (the only people here who assist are volunteers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ScreenX property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371529(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ScreenY property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371533(v=vs.85).aspx) has very little doco in the SDK. Presumably MSFT thought there was little to say.  As you can see from the log,  the client side "(c)" msiexec process has 1920x1080 but the server side "(s)" sees 1024x768.  It would seem this started happening in Vista but again the MSDN doco doesn't address it at all. Then there is the scenario of multiple monitors which it can't express at all.

[Some people](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28499) take ScreenX/Y and assign it to a secure custom public properties and then use that during the execute sequence (server side).  That wouldn't work during a silent install.  I suppose a custom action could query APIs (probably a wmi class) to get more information about the display adapter(s) present in the system.

My question though would be:  Why bother?

Resolution checks are best done in the application because the resolution could be changed after the install is done and because it's easier to do in application code anyways.

Comment: And there are multiple monitors too!

Comment: Thank you for your response : which is a shame it is that we can not check when installing the screen resolution ! we can do it in the application is true, but the person who installs the application should know quickly whether or not it can use the application ! in our case it must launch install and run the application and then is told not possible !

Comment: Then right a custom action. The wmi class Win32_DesktopMonitor should have what you are looking for.